# jQuery Draggable drags off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

When the user grabs the titlebar of a window and drags to the right all the way, the page will start to scroll right. Is there anyway to prevent this?

To reproduce: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
Drag the window to the right.

I have `overflow: hidden` on the `html` and `body` tags. Not sure what else to do here. I'd prefer not to use the containment option on the window because I want them to be able to slide off screen slightly.

Comment: Have you used jQuery UI draggable?

Comment: Those windows are using jquery draggable.

Comment: Note that the example posted in the code no longer demonstrates the issue. (Fixed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), you have an option called [Containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment). In that, you can specify the parent, inside which it should be constrained. In your case, the parent should be the `body`.

As an alternative, you could use the [scroll option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll):

```
$( "#outlook" ).draggable({ scroll: false });
```

Comment: To quote my question: `I'd prefer not to use the containment option on the window because I want them to be able to slide off screen slightly (like the actual Windows does).` But I don't want the mouse to be able to scroll off screen.

Comment: There is an option to not scroll. Did you see?

Comment: There it is. Add scroll to your answer.

Comment: I can't accept for a bit (5 minute limit). (Since there was an option for it, it's obviously time for bed - 2:30 am.) I didn't need the containment option in the answer though, just the scroll.

Comment: Sure, the text describes the constrain though while the code shows the scroll. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: The *constrain* option has been replaced with [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

Comment: @animuson How stupid of me. And how did you find out? `:P`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Lets say your main element is a div named 'myWindow';

```
document.getElementById('myWindow').scrolling = "no";
```